# Print double as raw hex?

Tags: java, double, hex

I'm interested in printing a double as raw hex. I don't want the mantissa and exponent interpreted.

Is there a print function in Java to accomplish it?

If not, how does one extract raw octets from a double in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)

Comment: Thanks kajacx. I just re-checked my search results, and the Oracle docs did not make the top 3 pages. My search skills must be really off today...

Comment: @jww Knowing a class or method name helps in picking search terms. To post my answer, I had to google the exact method name, but I knew it was in the `Double` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Double.doubleToLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) or [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)).

Answer (score 2):

First, get the bits as long, using [Double.doubleToLongBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) or [Double.doubleToRawLongBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)).

However if you would like to print the bits then and if you have Java 8, I would recommend converting your `long` to `String` using the new unsigned API, possibly with base 16 or 2.

```
double number = Math.E;
long bits = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(number);
System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(bits, 16)); // 4005bf0a8b145769
```